# Unable to create POD in kubernetes1 Getting error

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and creating a Pod with configmap. I created a yaml file to create a POD. But I am getting below error

error: error parsing yuvi.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: YAML: line 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context

My configmap name: yuviconfigmap

## YAML file:

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: yuvipod1
spec:
 containers:
   - name: yuvicontain
     image: nginx
     volumeMounts:
     - name: yuvivolume
        mountPath: /etc/voulme
  volumes:
  - name: yuvivolume
    configMap:
      name: yuviconfigmap
```

Comment: please write your yaml file in ``` ``` to show it properly and welcome

Comment: Sure Taybur!! Thanks for your information

Answer (score 1):

The yaml is not as per what kubernetes expects. Below should work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: yuvipod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: yuvicontain
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: yuvivolume
      mountPath: /etc/voulme
  volumes:
    - name: yuvivolume
      configMap:
        name: yuviconfigmap
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow..check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers